# JS Validate not working among forms

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am making a content management system as part of an assignment for university. I am looking to make the form validate the inputs, which has been done like this:

This all sits in the `<head>` tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

This script is below this, again in the `<head>` tag:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        $("#loginForm").validate();
    });
</script>
```

When I click on the login button, nothing happens and it does not validate when I am entering null data

Form markup:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="#" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="username" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter username"/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="password" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter password"/>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
```

I am new to using jQuery and following it, so could be very simple mistake but would need someone with more expertise than myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an attribute named `required` to fields you require, else the plugin won't know what values you actually require :)
See code example on https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

```
<input required ... />
```

If you don't want to bloat your markup, these rules can be configured via Javascript, too. You only need to pass a config-object to the validate method. The nitty-gritty is provided in the docs for `validate()`, but in essence, you provide a name as key, and the rules to apply to the element with that name:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("#loginForm").validate({
       password: "required", // converted to {required: true}
       username: {
           required: true,
           email: true
       }              
    });
});
</script>
```

All built-in rules can be found in the section titled "List of built-in Validation methods" on https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/